# java.lang.NullPointerException on installing Dev Suite 10g on Windows 10

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to install Dev Suite 10g on windows 10. I get the following error and the installation halts.

**java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixPathOps.concatPath(OiixPathOps.java:551)
  java.lang.NullPointerException      at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicOUIEntryPoint.processCommandLine(OiicOUIEntryPoint.java:390)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstaller.processCommandLine(OiicInstaller.java:442)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstaller.runInstaller(OiicInstaller.java:678)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstaller.main(OiicInstaller.java:628)**

The error screenshot is at the following location.

Comment: This is more a question for Oracle Support than for us.  However, if you did contact Oracle Support I suspect that they would just tell you that they don't support such an old version of Dev Suite on the latest version of Windows.  So I would recommend that you either use a later version of Dev Suite or an earlier version of Windows.

Comment: Seems like I need to downgrade the system to Windows 7, as I tried installing latest version of Dev suite, didn't find any success.